# How to check if a user is logged in or not in NextJS

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js, use-state, react-props

I am using Codeigniter 4 as backend and have completed the login page but am now stuck at how to check if the user has logged in or not I am using Next JS as frontend. What I have thought is to use useState hook to set the value to true and pass it as props then use ternary operators to check whether the user has logged in or not but I do not know how to pass it as a prop and do not know if this is a good way to do it.

Answer (score -3):

> Honour of the post edited: **react.js to next.js** in the question.
>
> Since, I am not into next.js development I can't continue to answer
> this post.
>
> Thanks.

***Below is my answer for react.js based auth control.***

Its good enough to protect the **Router**.

```
{userLoggedIn
      && (
        <Route
          path="/home"
          component={() => <Home />}
        />
      )}
```

**Brief:**

Here **userLoggedIn** is a state where we toggle after the login API call

**PS:**
Because, anyway you have to pass **Tokens (may be jwt)** in every API calls (API calls you wants to safe guard).

Comment: I do not understand how to use this as I am using a template and it has so many things and I have to check every page of the frontend

Comment: As far as as know, Next JS does not support  react-router

Comment: oh okay can you help me increase this post's reach as I am kind of stuckk

Comment: Actually honour of the post edited -> react.js to next.js. Have bit explained in the updated answer.